# How do you change the appearance of a reference list in overleaf

Tags: printing, latex, bibliography, ordering, reference-book

I am making a document in overleaf, latex, but I am running in some problems with the reference list. I have a reference bib package called references.bib with the following input:

```
@article{Laplaud,
    author = "{Laplaud, V. and Levernier, N., Pineau, J. and San Roman, M. and Barbier, L. and Saez, P.J. and ... Heyvingh, J.}",
    year = {2020},
    title = {Pinching the cortex of live cells reveals thickness instabilities caused by Myosin II motors.},
    journal = {bioRxiv},
    DOI = {10.1101/2020.09.28.316729}
}
```

The other articles that I want to cite are in the same format.

Then I added in the code:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
   \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

To print the reference list.

But the problem is that the list is printed with the initials before the last name, and I want it to print the initials after the last name. How do I do this? Also how do I add multiple authors without having to put `and` in between all authors?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT

This is a link to an MWE that I created in overleaf to show the problem:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/yxxdcvstjfqd (only viewing)

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example? (if you need some help, there is a guide how to create one for a document with a bibliography: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=606#a694)

Comment: I have added a link to an overleaf document which shows the problem!

Answer (score 0):

- To have the last name before the initials of the given name, you can define your own name format:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{default}{%
  \nameparts{#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
}
```

- you must not wrap the author field in `"..."` - this prevents biblatex from correctly formatting the list
- you must have an `and` between every author. That's the mandatory syntax of biblatex.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{Laplaud,
    author = {Laplaud, V. and Levernier, N. and Pineau, J. and San Roman, M. and Barbier, L. and Saez, P.J. and Heyvingh, J.},
    year = {2020},
    title = {Pinching the cortex of live cells reveals thickness instabilities caused by Myosin II motors.},
    journal = {bioRxiv},
    DOI = {10.1101/2020.09.28.316729}
}
@article{Akhmetova,
    author = {Akhmetova, K.A. and Chesnokov, I.N. and Fedorova, S.A.},
    year = {2018},
    title = {Functional Characterization of Septin Complexes.},
    journal = {Mol Biol (Mosk)},
    volume = {52(2)},
    pages = {155-171},
    DOI = {10.1134/S0026893317050028}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references.bib}


\DeclareNameFormat{default}{%
  \nameparts{#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
}


\begin{document}

When citing something the bibliography will show \cite{Laplaud}
As you can see \cite{Laplaud} does it correctly, however \cite{Akhmetova} does not

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!

One question still, using this site on how to reference an article: https://aut.ac.nz.libguides.com/APA6th/referencelist it says that when there are more than 7 authors you should add "..." between the sixth and last author, which is the case for "Laplaud et al", so how could I do that when I am not allowed to put the dots in?

Comment: @Aurian You could something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377614/36296